# Rails finding has_many child by child key, in a fancy way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm using Rails 4

Suppose I have, for example, a **Week** model that has_many **Days**

I know I can get a specific day with something like

`Week.take.days.where{ :week_day => 'mon' }.first`

But is there a simple way to get each day with something like

`Week.take.mon`

instead?

By "simple" I mean that I don't what to manually define a method or a relation for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a scope:

```
scope :having_week_day, ->(wday) { where(week_day: wday) }
```

And use it like this:

```
Week.having_week_day('mon')
```